# Create Variables from elements of a List of Lists Automatically R

Tags: r, function, loops, time-series, data-manipulation

I have a list of lists like below

```
str(list_ts_split)
List of 5
 $ date    :List of 2
  ..$ train: Time-Series [1:24] from 2019 to 2021: 1.55e+09 1.55e+09 1.55e+09 1.55e+09 
1.56e+09 ...
  ..$ test : Time-Series [1:6] from 2021 to 2021: 1.61e+09 1.61e+09 1.61e+09 1.62e+09 1.62e+09 
...
 $ actualB1:List of 2
  ..$ train: Time-Series [1:24] from 2019 to 2021: 5463 7618 3745 6760 5856 ...
  ..$ test : Time-Series [1:6] from 2021 to 2021: 5535 7326 6195 2435 3041 ...
     $ actualB2:List of 2
  ..$ train: Time-Series [1:24] from 2019 to 2021: 6523 1734 9544 4687 8076 ...
  ..$ test : Time-Series [1:6] from 2021 to 2021: 3647 9272 4974 5931 1459 ...
 $ actualAx:List of 2
  ..$ train: Time-Series [1:24] from 2019 to 2021: 193 200 310 149 719 357 470 623 678 533 ...
  ..$ test : Time-Series [1:6] from 2021 to 2021: 274 142 968 831 178 184
 $ actualAy:List of 2
  ..$ train: Time-Series [1:24] from 2019 to 2021: 3053 4351 3284 2155 1805 ...
  ..$ test : Time-Series [1:6] from 2021 to 2021: 8236 1585 2324 5692 4249 ...
```

I can access the elements of the list of lists using the code below

```
df1_tstrain <- list_ts_split$actualB1$train

df1_tstest <- list_ts_split$actualB1$test

list_ts_split $actualB1$train
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
 2019 5463 7618 3745 6760 5856 2645 4061 1162 6829 7584 8383 4016
 2020 2827 1666 3753 2004 1757 9360 5989 9031 1584 1435 8365 9209

 list_ts_split$actualB1$test
       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun
  2021 5535 7326 6195 2435 3041 2737
```

EDIT1: My question is, is there anyway to create a loop or use a function to do the same as
df1_tstrain <- actualB1$train      without me hard coding the value to a variable name in the global environment??

EDIT2:

I'm trying something like below right now

```
for (i in 1:length(list_ts_split)){
assign(paste0("tstrain",i}.as.data.frame(list_ts_split[[i]]))
}
```

Comment: I cannot figure out what is meant by "automatically". It appears you already know how to do it. Your code at the end is clearly not meant to be used in practice but rather appears to be attempting to convey some sort of operation that is  different in implementation than `df1_tstrain <- list_ts_split$actualB1$train`

Comment: Nooooo. DO NOT use commets to clarify the question. Use [edit] facilities. And what does it mean to " create a variable in the global environment, automatically without me hard coding it to a variable name". Why don't you wnat to give it a name?

Comment: For example, say I have list of 100 lists with each of those 100 lists containing 2 elements. I don't want to manually type in my R Script ... train1 <- list_ts_split$actualAx$train and test1 <- list_ts_split$actualAx$test ...100 times. I want a loop/function that can create those 100 variables of train1... train100 and test1...test100 for me instead of me writing 200 lines. I hope that clarifies what I'm saying

Comment: It is not a good practice to create multiple objects in the global environment like `df1_tstrain`, `df1_tstest` and so on. They pollute the global environment and it is very difficult to manage them. What is your next step after this? You can use `lapply`  on `list_ts_split` to perform the step on each list directly.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the case. I found a different solution that works well enough. I used do.call("rbind",list_ts_split) to create a list of each train/test so I can specify them with list_ts_split[[1]] and so on.

Comment: I basically want to be able to apply forecasting time series functions such as ets(), HoltWinters(), auto.arima to all of the ts() objects all at once, without manually writing each line for each time series.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a working example, so I am not sure I understand your problem. This being said, here is something to try out.

```
## Some data to work with
lst <- list(
  date = list(
    train = 2000:2010,
    test  = 2011:2021
  ),
  actualB1 = list(
    train = 2000:2010,
    test  = 2011:2021
  ),
  actualAx = list(
    train = 2000:2010,
    test  = 2011:2021
  )
)
## A function to subset the list at levels 1 and 2.
f <- function(lst, level_1, level_2){
  # l1 <- lst[[level_1]]
  # l1[[level_2]] 
  l1 <- sapply(X = lst, FUN = "[", level_2, simplify = FALSE)
  l1[[level_1]]
}
## testing the function on the list specifying the names of the 2 levels
test <- f(lst = lst, level_1 = 'actualB1', level_2 = 'train')
test
```

I am still not sure I understand the question, but here is another idea I put into a recursive function.

```
## Data

lst <- list(
  date = data.frame(
    train = 2000:2005,
    test  = 2005:2010
  ),
  actualB1 = data.frame(
    train = 2010:2015,
    test  = 2015:2020
  ),
  actualAx = data.frame(
    train = 2020:2025,
    test  = 2030:2035
  )
)

# Function

f <- function(lst){
  names_lst <- names(lst)
  lapply(X = names_lst, function(i){
    if(inherits(lst[[i]], what = 'data.frame', which = TRUE)){
      names_i <- names(lst[[i]])
      lapply(X = names_i, function(j){
        obj_name <- paste(i, j, sep = "_")
        assign(obj_name, lst[[i]][[j]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
      })
    } else {
      f (lst)
    }
  })
}

# Function called on Data

test <- f(lst = lst)
```

[image: Overview of the global environment]

The raison why I am not sure whether I understand your problem is that I, can't seems to see why one would want to keep subset-ing a list and assigning the results to new objects.

I think you need to rethink your approach if you want to do further analysis with the data you are subset-ing. While the function above does generically retrieve the names at different level of nesting of the list, it may run into the error `C stack usage  <number> is too close to the limit`, depending on your settings. This may be a sign that you may need to rethink your approach. Try adding more level of nesting to `lst` and you may eventually get into that error. On my machine, the following led me that error:

```
lst <- list(
  date = data.frame(
    train   = 2000:2005,
    test    = 2005:2010
  ),
  actualB1  = data.frame(
    train   = 2010:2015,
    test    = 2015:2020
  ),
  actualAx  = list(
    up      = data.frame(
      train = 2020:2025,
      test  = 2030:2035
    ),
    sub     = data.frame (
      train = 2040:2045,
      test  = 2045:2050
    )
  )
)
test <- f(lst = lst) # Error: C stack usage  15926032 is too close to the limit
```

Comment: Yeah this is helpful! To clarify more, I'm trying to create a vector or dataframe for each train and test in each list in a loop. So in your example for lst, since there is 3 lists (date,actualB1,actualAx) I want 6 vectors/dfs (because 2 elements in each list) within a loop of some sorts. Basically if I had 100 lists of 2 elements each (date=,actualB1=,actualA1,actualG1,etc...to 100), I would need 200 lines of code, for the 100*2 vectors/dfs. Trying to make my code more concise

Comment: I know how to do it "manually" by using lst$date$train in your example to extract 2000:2010 into a variable (date_train<- lst$date$train), but if I had 100 different train/tests I wouldn't want to write the code 200 times...(date_train1....date_train100 <- lst$the_100th_list_name$train) So I'd want an "automated way" in the form of loop or function. Maybe this is too hard in R. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Ok, check out my edits, and keep me posted!